# Time analysis of binary search tree operations

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I read about binary search trees that if it is a complete tree (all nodes except leaf nodes have two children) having n nodes, then no path can have more than 1+log n nodes.

Here is the calculation I did... can you show me where did I go wrong....

```
the first level of bst has only one node(i.e. the root)-->2^0
the second level have 2 nodes(the children of root)---->2^1
the third level has 2^3=8 nodes
 .
 .
the (x+1)th level has 2^x nodes

so the total number of nodes =n = 2^0 +2^1 +2^2 +...+2^x = 2^(x+1)-1
so, x=log(n+1)-1

now as it is a 'complete' tree...the longest path(which has most no of nodes)=x
and so the nodes experienced in this path is x+1= log(n+1)
```

Then how did the number 1+log n come up...?

Comment: What is your definition of path? Do you view the tree as a directed (edges go only from parent to children nodes) or undirected (edges go "both ways") graph?

Comment: @Philippe...it is an undirected graph

Comment: OK... the log(n+1) - 1 bound seems to correspond to the maximum length for a path from the _root_ to any node, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter answer: the number `x` of levels in a complete (or perfect) binary tree is `log2(n+1)`, where `n` is the number of nodes (alternatively, `n = 2^(x-1)`). A tree with `x` levels has height `x-1`. The longest path from the root to any node contains `x = log2(n+1)` nodes (and `x-1` edges).

Now because `n+1` is a power of 2, we have that `log2(n+1) = 1 + floor(log2(n))`. In other words, `1 + log2(n)` is a correct upper-bound, but it is never an integer.

It is unclear to me whether the `x` in your computation refers to the height or the number of levels.

Comment: @philippie...in my computation as i start from root as 1st level which has 2^0 nodes.....so my (x+1)th level has 2^x nodes...and x is the total height of (x+1)th level...